# Получение items через menu.xml

Tags: android, xml

Либо другими словами, нужно найти расстояние между вертикальными черными полосами. Количество item'ов в тулбаре может быть любым, либо их вообще может не быть.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPDATE:
Пробегая по child элементам тулбара выяснил что то что мне нужно найти - отдельный View, но без каких либо особенностей(ни id ни тега).

Comment: Мне не понятно зачем?! Ведь main.xml относится к неизменяемым ресурсам, вы сами указываете там все что вам надо, и знаете что и куда вы указали, зачем вам получать обходными путями то, что вы и так знаете, у вас это указано в xml и программно до отрисовки изменяться не будет.

Comment: @ВиталийОбидейко, Я пишу собственную мини библиотеку, и мне просто необходимо узнать расстояние между крайним правым элементом в тулбаре(setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled) и крайним левым элементом(либо три точки, либо другие элементы если есть showAsAction)

Comment: Если с такой стороны, тогда понятно, но это следовало указать в вопросе, тогда небыло бы вопросов таких.)

Comment: @ВиталийОбидейко, сейчас обновлю вопрос, приложу скрин. И, количество кнопок в тулбаре может быть любое,либо их вообще может не быть. Есть какие советы как это определить?

Comment: Вы можете получить значение битовой маски `mShowAsAction` через рефлексию, и с ее помощью исходя из density экрана определить, сколько итемов будет показано.

Comment: Может быть можно как то найти этот элемент не основываясь на menu.xml. В данный момент мне удалось получить child элементы toolbar'a, то что мне нужно найти - View, в центре, но не id ничего особенного нет у этой view

Comment: Акромя id вьюху можно вычислить по её положению относительно родителя методом `getChildAt(int index)`